# file upload using axios in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, nestjs

I am uploading file in `react` using `axios`.
when I am doing

```
alert(values.attachedFile[0]);
```

[image]

but when I am sending `values.attachedFile[0]` in `axios` post request enpty thing is going.

```
  const { result } = await axios.post(app.resourceServerUrl + '/file/upload', {
        data: values.attachedFile[0],
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
    });
```

but as part of request is is going empty.

[image]

what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Show source code of nest.js controller who manage the route `file/upload`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To upload file with axios you need to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```
const formData = new FormData();

// ...

formData.append("data", values.attachedFile[0]);
axios.post(app.resourceServerUrl + '/file/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```